# How can I run two python subprocesses and grab their runtimes and stdout, stderr?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess

I was looking into running two subprocesses at the same time on one machine so that I can get accurate runtimes. I am comparing two versions of software and running diagnostics on them, such as runtime, output variation, etc.

Originally I had one function that uses both versions of the software on the same input file, and each outputs to a different place. The old and new versions are grabbed through an argparser. The function uses a subprocess for each software command, and then the output is grabbed through .communicate(). But I know that .communicate() waits for the process to finish, ideally I want to use .communicate() on both processes at the same time so that they start at the same time, and are timed, and will give me results whenever as long as I know their runtimes.

My question, more concisely, is how can I run two subprocesses each running individually and starting at the same time. And then grab their runtimes and stdout, stderr?

Heres a quick example of my function (just pretend im testing speeds of java on some file):

```
def test():
    # Get start time        
    before = time.time()
    cmd1 = ['java-1.0', 'blah']
    c1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    cmd2 = ['java-1.5', 'blah']
    c2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    # Start both processes at the same time??
    results = [c1.communicate(), c2.communicate()]
    # Get total time taken
    total = round(time.time()-before, 2)
    # Print out the total time (I know its messy but its accurate)
    print "%s:%s:%s" % (int(total/60/60), int(total/60), int(total))
    c1.stderr.close()
    c2.stderr.close()
    return results
```

Another point I want to make is that I need them to run at the same time because if I am running a job on a powerful remote machine (which I will be) then I need the workload to be the same while running the jobs so that one process doesn't finish faster just because it ran at a different time.

Comment: Rather than pretend, be direct with us. If you're really testing the speed of two external programs, the best approach would be pretty different than if you just need to run things (and very different from what you've written here). Share in more detail what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Your use of `round` here is not ideal (In fact, `round` isn't useful at all ever.). If you want to round off the number of seconds, use the `%0.2f` format specifier or something.

Comment: I didn't realize a built in function like round was completely irrelevant, but that doesn't really have anything to do with solving my problem. So anyways, what do you mean be more direct? I am not pretending anything, and yes I want to test two different versions of a piece of software on the same data and compare their outputs, and speeds. Specifically I am testing different versions of picard. The newer versions are supposedly up to 5x faster, so I want to test this as well as make sure that both versions give the same result!

Comment: Can anyone help please, I am stuck. I really need this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get *accurate* runtimes, you'll need to run the test many times and look at the distribution -- the median runtime should be a good indicator. Running both of them at the same time won't help you get more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

Runtimes testing is usually done on an otherwise idle machine and repeated several times with and without different input files to get an idea what the influence of the OS caches are.

Having two processes vying for the same resources will *not* result in more accurate measurements.

Speeding up Python programs is usually a case of using the right tools. E.g. list- and other comprehensions are usually faster than loops. And using built-in functions probably trumps that. A nice example is "[an optimization anecdote](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html)". Probably the best optimization is a different algorithm.

Using PyPy instead of CPython might also yield significant improvement.

Comment: Your advice about Python optimization seems out-of-place in this thread and possibly harmful. (The essay you link has a lot of truth to it, but as practical advice about how to speed up stuff in Python, it is very out-of-date.)

Comment: My line of thought was that as a rule, measureing is done when code is perceived as slow. Which part of the conclusions would you consider outdated?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you have no input to send to the process you don't need to use `Popen.communicate()`. The Popen call itself starts the process, we do not need `Popen.communicate()` for that. You can use `Popen.poll()` to check if a process is finished instead of using Popen.communicate().

```
while True:
    if c1.poll() is not None:
        #Stop c1's timer
    if c2.poll() is not None:
        #Stop c2's timer
```

If you want stdout and stderr, you can spawn 2 threads and then use `Popen.communicate()` and record the time.

You can use something like this as a thread:

```
def time_it(c):
    results.append(c.communicate())
    times.append(time.time())
```

To spawn the threads, call

```
results = []
times = []
threading.start_new_thread(time_it,(c1,))
threading.start_new_thread(time_it,(c2,))
```

Comment: Since he's collecting the stdout and stderr of this process, your technique will not work.

Comment: I am trying to save the stdout and stderr too.

Comment: You can use c.communicate() instead of c.wait() in the time_it function, if you need stdout and stderr

Comment: You might want to use a lock as well to make sure the data always gets appended properly.